# Update account id in contact using maps

Tags: apex

I am given a relationship object having `Businessname` field (master detail with account) and individual field (lookup with contact). How to create trigger on relationship to update Businessname on contact attached in relationship record?

```
trigger ContactUpdate on Relationship__c (before insert) {
 Map<Id,String> con=new Map<Id,String>();

    for(Relationship__c rec :Trigger.new){
        con.put(rec.Individual__c,rec.BusinessName__c);
    }

    List<contact> contList=new List<contact>();

    for(Contact cont: [Select Id,Account.Id From contact where Id IN :con.keySet() ]){


        if(Trigger.new.get(BusinessName__c)!=cont.Account.Id){
           cont.Account.Id=Trigger.new.get(BusinessName__c);

        contList.add(cont);
    }
     Update contList;   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This trigger should not compile, as there are several key errors in this block of code.

```
for(Contact cont: [SELECT Id, Account.Id FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :con.keySet() ]) {
    if (Trigger.new.get(BusinessName__c)!=cont.Account.Id){
       cont.Account.Id=Trigger.new.get(BusinessName__c);
       contList.add(cont);
    }
    update contList;   
}
```

I've reformatted this code so that its structure will be more apparent. Here are some of the issues here.

1. Using `Account.Id` instead of `AccountId`. At best, this adds an extra join/relationship traversal that you don't need, but here, it creates another issue (below).
2. `Trigger.new` is a `List<sObject>`, not a `Map<Id, sObject>`. In `Trigger.newMap`, the keys are `Id`s of the trigger object (here, `Relationship__c`), not `Account`, so doing `Trigger.newMap.get(BusinessName__c)` will at best return `null`. (Even if `BusinessName__c` were defined, which it's not). You should be referencing the `Map` you already created, using the Contact's `Id` as the key.
3. Assigning to `cont.Account.Id` does not change the relationship, which is stored on `cont.AccountId`.
4. You are running a DML operation inside a loop. That's a bad practice in general; here, it's pathological because you're updating the entire list every time through the loop.

As a separate comment, this functionality appears to me to be duplicative of out of the box functionality like Contacts to Multiple Accounts.

Comment: trigger.newMap.get(Business__c) is giving errors saying business__c not found..What to do?

Comment: @Ashi Did you see point 2 in my answer? It explains this issue.

Comment: Can you please tell how to refer to map I am stuck at this point?

Comment: Your code already builds a map between Contact Ids and Account Ids. You should be using that Map.

Comment: I know I need to use that map but I dont know how to put that down in the code.